# How to copy file remotely to remote windows servers via ansible

Tags: windows, ansible

Shortly:

```
Ansible Control Machine : ServerC
Source Machine : ServerA
Destination Machine : ServerB
```

I want to send a file from serverA to serverB via serverC(ansible).I tried with win_copy but doesn't work because of remote servers.

```
---
-
  hosts: ServerA
  tasks:
    -
      delegate_to: ServerB
      name: "Transfer file from ServerA to ServerB"
      synchronize:
        dest: "C:\\Temp\\"
        mode: pull
        src: "C:\\Temp\\test"
```

Thank you

@imjoseangel When I edited as you said, I get like this error any idea?

```
PLAY [Sync Files] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ServerA]

TASK [Sync ServerA to ServerB] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ServerA]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": " C:\\Temp\\test.gz \\ServerB\\c$\\TEMP /purge /e", "dest": "\\ServerB\\c$\\TEMP", "flags": null, "msg": "2018/07/11 09:11:50 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\\Temp\\test.gz\\", "output": ["", "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------", "   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              ", "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------", "", "  Started : Wednesday, July 11, 2018 9:11:50 AM", "   Source : C:\\Temp\\test.gz\\", "     Dest : C:\\ServerB\\c$\\TEMP\\", "", "    Files : *.*", "\t    ", "  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /R:1000000 /W:30 ", "", "------------------------------------------------------------------------------", "", "2018/07/11 09:11:50 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\\Temp\\test.gz\\", "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.", ""], "purge": true, "rc": 16, "recurse": true, "return_code": 16, "src": "C:\\Temp\\test.gz"}
 [WARNING]: Could not create retry file '/etc/ansible/test/test.retry'.         [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/etc/ansible/test/test.retry'


PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ServerA              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

My recent yaml:

```
---
- name: Sync Files
  hosts: ServerA

  tasks:
  - name: Sync ServerA to ServerB
    win_robocopy:
      src: "C:\\Temp\\test.gz"
      dest: "\\ServerB\\c$\\TEMP"
      recurse: true
      purge: true
```

Comment: `synchronize` module is for Linux Server. Use `win_robocopy` to copy files on Windows. I can see that are remote servers but CIFS is one option. Which ports do you have opened?

Comment: 80,443,445 ports are open.

Comment: Cool, Could you please confirm you have also 139/TCP? Without that port, you can only use IP instead of names for CIFS.

Comment: Yea, It's also open.Additional note:My ansible machine is linux.ServerA and B are windows machine.

Comment: Hey put the file as option.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
  ---
  - name: Sync Files
    hosts: ServerA

  - name: Sync ServerA to ServerB
    win_robocopy:
      src: "C:\\Temp\\"
      dest: "\\ServerB\\c$\\Temp"
      recurse: yes
      purge: yes
```

**Output:**

```
"msg": "Files copied successfully!",
"output": [
    "",
    "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
    "   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              ",
    "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
    "",
    "  Started : Thursday, July 5, 2018 12:02:15",
    "   Source : C:\\Temp\\",
    "     Dest : C:\\ServerB\\c$\\Temp\\",
    "",
    "    Files : *.*",
    "\t    ",
    "  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /R:1000000 /W:30 ",
    "",
    "------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
```

> **Note:** You don't have to delegate to ServerB as ServerA is doing the job.

Comment: I tried as you said, I get the error(posted on main post.)

Comment: `ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\\Temp\\test.gz\\ ` Can you check the file and dir exists? Did you remove also the `delegate_to` ?

Comment: Yea, file still in there.I edited my recent yaml upper post.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear in the title if you want to copy from windows to windows, so in case one wants to copy large files from the Ansible machine to a remote one, I wrote [this article](https://yayimorphology.org/ansible-windows-transfer-large-files.html). Basically the steps are as follow:

1. creates a network shared folder on the windows machine
2. mounts that network folder from the linux machine
3. transfers the files
4. clean up everything

Step1 can be done like this (general idea, more info in the article itself):

```
- name: Add share on the remote
  win_share:
    name: ansible-work-dir
    description: for pushing ansible stuff
    path: "{{ destination_folder }}"
    list: yes
    full: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
```

while step2 depends on the OS in use. For Ubuntu/Linux, I use the following

```
- name: Mount local folder
  shell: gio mount smb://{{ ansible_host }}/ansible-work-dir < {{ thefile.path }}
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: False
  register: command_result
  failed_when:
    - command_result.rc != 0
    - not ('Location is already mounted' in command_result.stderr)
```

The transfer of the file itself in Step3 becomes a file copy on the Ansible machine, as the remote share is mounted.